# Determining arg of a complex number in Euler form

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, angle

I am trying to solve $arg(3e^{10i})$ and the solution should be $10-4\pi=-2,5664$. However, I have my problems understanding and getting to this solution.

I would assume that you could rewrite $$arg(3e^{10i})=arg (3(cos(10)+isin(10))$$ and since we want to find $\theta$ from this solution it would equal $arccos cos \theta)=\theta=10$. However, since we know that every rotation of radian $2\pi$ would lead to the same point, I would divide $10:2\pi=1.5915$ and $10-2\pi$ since it is only possible to go one full round (1.5915).

This ansatz and reasoning seems wrong. Can anyone help to explain it to me or show me a detailed solution path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They want you to determine $arg(z)$ in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. Since $arg(z)=Arg(z)+2\pi k$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$ where $Arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$, we have $Arg(z)=10-2\pi k$. Which value of $k$ will give you $Arg(z)$ in the correct interval?

Comment: There was no requirement about an interval, I think they just wanted **a** solution? So basically, if it would be just **a** solution, $10-2\pi$ would be also a correct answer?

Comment: It’s because we normally define $arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$ so that there isn’t more than one answer. Yes that would be a correct answer, as would $10$, and any other integer multiple of $2\pi$ from $10$

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know about the definition of the interval of arg(z). Besides the solution, my solution path would be also kind of correct right? Actually it could be simplified as we simply know that $re^{\theta i}$. However, I also wonder what role r=3 plays in this task? Can we simply ignore it? Isn't $2\pi$ only the radian of a circle with the radius of 1?

Comment: $arg(z)$ is literally the $\theta$ in $re^{i\theta}$, $r$ doesn’t play a role

Answer (score 1):

The argument is simply $10.$ If you don't want arguments less than $0$ or more than $2π,$ then this is expressible as $10-2π.$ If you allow negative arguments then the least such in magnitude is $10-4π.$

Comment: Yeah, now I get why we could also subtract $2*2\pi$. It actually does make sense, since any point could be reached by clockwise or counterclockwise rotation. So basically my answer would be correct?

Comment: @randomname Yes both, and infinitely more, may be considered equivalent modulo $2π.$